# Cannot Update with case Statement

Tags: oracle

I have query like this

```
update mst_doc_proc_list set is_display = 0, is_mandatory = 1, is_deleted = case
    when (is_display = 1 and is_mandatory = 1) then 1 else 0 end
    where eff_date = '11/4/2017';
```

When I first execution just `is_display` and `is_mandatory` updated.
I have to execute two times to update all that is in the query. What should I do to run these queries in a single execution?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do? What are the original values before you execute any update and what is the expected outcome that you want after executing the update the first time?

Answer (score 0):

`is_display` and `is_mandatory` in your `CASE` statement take the current value from the row, and not your new values.

In your example query, you literally have `set is_display = 0` which means you do not need a case statement at all, you can also hardcode it to `0`.

In your real query are you using bind variables for the values of `is_display` and `is_mandatory`?  If you are, then use bind variables for these values in both spots:

```
update mst_doc_proc_list set is_display = ?, is_mandatory = ?, is_deleted = case
       when (is_display = ? and is_mandatory = ?) then 1 else 0 end
       where eff_date = '11/4/2017';
```

Alternatively, I would probably put this logic in the code and not the SQL.

```
update mst_doc_proc_list set is_display = ?, is_mandatory = ?, is_deleted = ?
       where eff_date = '11/4/2017';
```